# bundle install failing with error Zlib::DataError: invalid distance too far back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zlib

I am running bundle install command by going into my docker container and i am getting below error

```
root@internal:/srv/deviceservice# bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching source index from https://gems.contribsys.com/
Fetching source index from https://gems.contribsys.com/
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies................
RubyGems 1.8.23 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to RubyGems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Fetching rake 10.4.2
Zlib::DataError: invalid distance too far back
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  coffee-rails was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on
    railties was resolved to 3.2.21, which depends on
      rake
root@internal:/srv/deviceservice# gem install rake -v '10.4.2'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::DataError)
    invalid distance too far back
root@internal:/srv/deviceservice#
```

My ruby version is 1.9.3 and rails version is '3.2.21' . i was not able to find anything related to this issue on the internet.  any idea what this error is coming ?

Answer (score 0):

It means the data is corrupted. Either in transit or at the source.